# add class of global S3 object within a function, avoiding the `<<-` operator

Tags: r

I am defining an S3 object inside a function and assigning it to a variable in the global environment; subsequently within the same function I am adding an additional class to it. The only way I was able to do it was using the `<<-` operator, which I would prefer to avoid as from my reading it actually assigns to the parent environment and this can be dangerous. Ideally, I would like to use `assign`, but the first argument is the variable name so it fails. Any suggestions on how this could be better achieved without using `<<-`?

For the record I also tried the normal assignment operator `<-`, but this also fails and don't understand why, since the variable is already defined globally.

Some illustrative examples below:

```
# <<- assigns to parent environment, if "lucky" that is the globalenv, me no gusto :(
foo_works_dragons <- function(addclass) {
  fooobj <- structure(list(), class = "Alpha")
  assign("G_FOOOBJ", fooobj, envir = globalenv())
  class(G_FOOOBJ) <<- c(class(G_FOOOBJ), addclass)
  return(TRUE)
}


# prefer assign statement but function argument x is "a variable name" from man page, so ok not working, any suggestions?
foo_fails_nodragons <- function(addclass) {
  fooobj <- structure(list(), class = "Alpha")
  assign("G_FOOOBJ", fooobj, envir = globalenv())
  assign("class(G_FOOOBJ)", c(class(G_FOOOBJ), addclass), envir = globalenv())
  return(TRUE)
}


# fails, don't understand though why
foo_fails_but_why <- function(addclass) {
  fooobj <- structure(list(), class = "Alpha")
  assign("G_FOOOBJ", fooobj, envir = globalenv())
  class(G_FOOOBJ) <- c(class(G_FOOOBJ), addclass)
  return(TRUE)
}


foo_works_dragons("Beta")
print(class(G_FOOOBJ))
# [1] "Alpha" "Beta"
rm(G_FOOOBJ)

foo_fails_nodragons("Beta")
print(class(G_FOOOBJ))
# [1] "Alpha"
rm(G_FOOOBJ)

foo_fails_but_why("Beta")
print(class(G_FOOOBJ))
# [1] "Alpha"
rm(G_FOOOBJ)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use envir$object notation:

```
foo <- function(addclass, envir = .GlobalEnv) {
  envir$G_FOOOBJ <- structure(list(), class = "Alpha")
  class(envir$G_FOOOBJ) <- c(class(envir$G_FOOOBJ), addclass)
  return(TRUE)
}

if (exists("G_FOOOBJ")) rm(G_FOOOBJ)
foo("Beta")
## [1] TRUE

G_FOOOBJ
## list()
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "Alpha" "Beta"
```

If you really want to use `assign` then this works:

```
foo2 <- function(addclass, envir = .GlobalEnv) {
  fooobj <- structure(list(), class = "Alpha")
  assign("G_FOOOBJ", structure(fooobj, class = c(class(fooobj), addclass)), envir)
  return(TRUE)
}

if (exists("G_FOOOBJ")) rm(G_FOOOBJ)
foo2("Beta")
## [1] TRUE

G_FOOOBJ
## list()
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "Alpha" "Beta"
```